# Unwrapping multiple TryAsync

Tags: c#, haskell, monads, language-ext

cIn haskell i can have :

```
do 
   result1 <- IOaction1
   result2 <- IOaction2
   doSomethingWith result1 result2
```

How can i achive this in C# with LanguageExt ?

**Edit**

```
EitherAsync<string,int> x = TryAsync<int>(new Exception()).ToEither(err=>"sgp");
EitherAsync<string,int> y = TryAsync<int>(new Exception()).ToEither(err => "str");
```

How can i now perform a bind over `x` and then over `y` , and unwrap both values and use them in a new method to wrap the result ?

Something like:

```
x.Bind y.Bind 
-> (int xUnwrapped,int yUnwrapped) -> RightAsync<string,int>(xUnwrapped+yUnwrapped)
```

Comment: Doesn't `await` work for you? Why?

Comment: I know nothing about C#, but my guess is `ioaction1.bind((result1) => ioaction2.bind((result2) => doSomething(result1,result2)))`. In Haskell the `do` block can also be written in this form using `ioaction1 >>= \result1 -> ....`.

Comment: You need to provide a complete example of how you are trying to accomplish this with LanguageExt. I can't find the overload you are using.

Comment: @chi its exactly what i'm trying to do in C#. I have a EitherAsync<A,B> and a another EitherAsync<C,D>. I want to unwrap the first Either if succesful then unwrap the second Either and then perform some computation on B,D and wrap them up in another EitherAsync. For haskell an either async would be an IO Something that goes into an Either

Comment: Have you tried `await`? Did it not work? If so, why?

Comment: I need to pipeline them. What has await have to do with it ?

Comment: You keep mentioning bind. `await` is what bind is called in C# for tasks.